# Unusual Kronecker Symbol

Tags: kronecker-delta, kronecker-symbol

I am studying on an article about the Galerkin method and I found this symbole $\delta_{ij}^{km}$.
I know the definition of the usual Kronecker Symbol  which is :
$$\delta_{ij}=\cases{1&if $i=j$\\0&else},$$
I can't understand what $\delta_{ij}^{km}$ means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\delta_{ij}^{km}
= \frac12\left( \delta_i^k \delta_j^m - \delta_j^k \delta_i^m \right)
$$
(I'm a bit unsure about the factor $\frac12$.)

Comment: Normalizations are compared [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta#Definitions_of_the_generalized_Kronecker_delta).

Comment: @Ada Az, I'm sure you know it, but for clarity for less experienced future readers, $\delta_i^k$ is effectively the same thing as $\delta_{ik}$.